# Why aren't my buttons properly aligned with python TKinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, button, alignment

I am creating a password manager which includes some buttons, but for some reason these buttons aren't aligning properly, could someone help out?
Here is the code i've done usint Tkinter for these buttons:

```
  btn = Button(window, text="Exit Securely", command=exit)
btn.grid(column=2)
btn = Button(window, text="Add Entry", command=addEntry)
btn.grid(column=1)
btn = Button(window, text="Generate", command=run)
btn.grid(column=0)


lbl = Label(window, text="Website")
lbl.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=80)
lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
lbl.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=80)
lbl = Label(window, text="password")
lbl.grid(row=3, column=2, padx=80)
```

which makes my program look like this: [image]

Any general tips or helpful links for how to make a nicer GUI would be appreciated as well, as I have been struggling with that.

Comment: You need to specify `row` in `grid()`, otherwise it will take the next available row.

Answer (score 0):

As @acw1668 said if you don't specify `row` in `grid()`, it will take the next available row.

```py
# Code to make this example work:
from tkinter import *

def addEntry():pass
def run():pass

window = Tk()

# Added `row=0` for each one of them
btn = Button(window, text="Exit Securely", command=exit)
btn.grid(row=0, column=2)
btn = Button(window, text="Add Entry", command=addEntry)
btn.grid(row=0, column=1)
btn = Button(window, text="Generate", command=run)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0)


# Changed the row to 1 for all of them
lbl = Label(window, text="Website")
lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=80)
lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
lbl.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=80)
lbl = Label(window, text="password")
lbl.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=80)
```

By the way it is a good idea to use different names for the different buttons/labels.

Comment: Thank you very much, I soon figured it out anyway, the advice is appreciated though, i'll do that now.

Comment: Instead of referencing what someone else said, this answer would be better if you explained the root of the problem directly in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying various method of aligning the widgets of tkinter in the program window lately and well I have found a better working solution to this.

In you program you have been using `grid` for aligning. I would say that you replace with `place` instead.

`place` will allow you to set a definite x and y coordinate for the widget and it would be easy to use.

If I alter your code accordingly, I can show you the code (after alteration) and the image of the output.

---

**Code (After Alteration)**

```
# Code to make this example work:
from tkinter import *

def addEntry():pass
def run():pass

window = Tk()

# Adding geometry ettig.
window.geometry('500x500')

btn = Button(window, text="Exit Securely", command=exit)
btn.place(x=410, y=20)
btn = Button(window, text="Add Entry", command=addEntry)
btn.place(x=210, y=20)
btn = Button(window, text="Generate", command=run)
btn.place(x=10, y=20)


lbl = Label(window, text="Website")
lbl.place(x=10, y=50)
lbl = Label(window, text="Username")
lbl.place(x=210, y=50)
lbl = Label(window, text="password")
lbl.place(x=410, y=50)
```

**The Output Screen**

[image]